Did the German justice system convict a woman for insulting a person who gang raped a minor?
New York Post writes

A German woman was handed down a harsher sentence than a convicted rapist after she called him a “disgraceful rapist pig.”
Maja R, 20, was jailed for a weekend after she was found guilty of defaming the man, who was one of nine attackers who had gang-raped a 15-year-old girl in a Hamburg park four years earlier, according to reports.
The man had only been given a suspended sentence and served no time in prison due to his age, the New Zealand Herald reported.


Did the German justice system convict a woman for insulting a person who gang raped a minor?
If so, did she receive a harsher sentence than the rapist?


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
